# Simply using parsec in python

Tags: python, parsec, parser-combinators

I'm looking at this library, which has little documentation:
https://pythonhosted.org/parsec/#examples

I [understand there are alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94952/python-implementation-of-parsec), but I'd like to use this library.

I have the following string I'd like to parse:

```
mystr = """
<kv>
  key1: "string"
  key2: 1.00005
  key3: [1,2,3]
</kv>
<csv>
date,windspeed,direction
20190805,22,NNW
20190805,23,NW
20190805,20,NE
</csv>"""
```

While I'd like to parse the whole thing, I'd settle for just grabbing the `<tags>`. I have:

```
>>> import parsec
>>> tag_start = parsec.Parser(lambda x: x == "<")
>>> tag_end = parsec.Parser(lambda x: x == ">")
>>> tag_name = parsec.Parser(parsec.Parser.compose(parsec.many1, parsec.letter))
>>> tag_open = parsec.Parser(parsec.Parser.joint(tag_start, tag_name, tag_end))
```

OK, looks good.  Now to use it:

```
>>> tag_open.parse(mystr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This fails.  I'm afraid I don't even understand what it meant about my lambda expression giving two arguments, it's clearly 1.  How can I proceed?

My optimal desired output for all the bonus points is:

```
[
{"type": "tag", 
 "name" : "kv",
 "values"  : [
    {"key1" : "string"},
    {"key2" : 1.00005},
    {"key3" : [1,2,3]}
  ]
},
{"type" : "tag",
"name" : "csv", 
"values" : [
    {"date" : 20190805, "windspeed" : 22, "direction": "NNW"}
    {"date" : 20190805, "windspeed" : 23, "direction": "NW"}
    {"date" : 20190805, "windspeed" : 20, "direction": "NE"}
  ]
}
```

The output I'd settle for understanding in this question is using functions like those described above for start and end tags to generate:

```
[
  {"tag": "kv"},
  {"tag" : "csv"}
]
```

And simply be able to parse arbitrary xml-like tags out of the messy mixed text entry.

Comment: For starters, the lambda needs to take two arguments and return `Value.success()` or `Value.failure()` as mentioned [here](https://pythonhosted.org/parsec/documentation.html#parsec.Parser).

Comment: But `fn` *must* accept two arguments. It is passed the entire text and current index.

Comment: Here you see examples of the usage: https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py/blob/master/tests/test_parsec.py

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I encourage you to define your own parser using those combinators, rather than construct the `Parser` directly.

If you want to construct a `Parser` by wrapping a function, as the documentation states, the `fn` should accept two arguments, the first is the text and the second is the current position. And `fn` should return a `Value` by `Value.success` or `Value.failure`, rather than a boolean. You can grep `@Parser` in the `parsec/__init__.py` in this package to find more examples of how it works.

For your case in the description, you could define the parser as follows:

```py
from parsec import *

spaces = regex(r'\s*', re.MULTILINE)
name = regex(r'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*')

tag_start = spaces >> string('<') >> name << string('>') << spaces
tag_stop = spaces >> string('</') >> name << string('>') << spaces

@generate
def header_kv():
    key = yield spaces >> name << spaces
    yield string(':')
    value = yield spaces >> regex('[^\n]+')
    return {key: value}

@generate
def header():
    tag_name = yield tag_start
    values = yield sepBy(header_kv, string('\n'))
    tag_name_end = yield tag_stop
    assert tag_name == tag_name_end
    return {
        'type': 'tag',
        'name': tag_name,
        'values': values
    }

@generate
def body():
    tag_name = yield tag_start
    values = yield sepBy(sepBy1(regex(r'[^\n<,]+'), string(',')), string('\n'))
    tag_name_end = yield tag_stop
    assert tag_name == tag_name_end
    return {
        'type': 'tag',
        'name': tag_name,
        'values': values
    }

parser = header + body
```

If you run `parser.parse(mystr)`, it yields

```
({'type': 'tag',
  'name': 'kv',
  'values': [{'key1': '"string"'},
             {'key2': '1.00005'},
             {'key3': '[1,2,3]'}]},
 {'type': 'tag',
  'name': 'csv',
  'values': [['date', 'windspeed', 'direction'],
             ['20190805', '22', 'NNW'],
             ['20190805', '23', 'NW'],
             ['20190805', '20', 'NE']]}
)
```

You can refine the definition of `values` in the above code to get the result in the exact form you want.

Answer (score 8):

According to the tests, the proper way to parse your string would be the following:

```
from parsec import *

possible_chars = letter() | space() |  one_of('/.,:"[]') | digit()
parser =  many(many(possible_chars) + string("<") >> mark(many(possible_chars)) << string(">"))

parser.parse(mystr)
# [((1, 1), ['k', 'v'], (1, 3)), ((5, 1), ['/', 'k', 'v'], (5, 4)), ((6, 1), ['c', 's', 'v'], (6, 4)), ((11, 1), ['/', 'c', 's', 'v'], (11, 5))]
```

The construction of the `parser`:

---

For the sake of convenience, we first define the characters we wish to match. `parsec` provides many types:

- `letter()`: matches any alphabetic character,
- `string(str)`: matches any specified string `str`,
- `space()`: matches any whitespace character,
- `spaces()`: matches multiple whitespace characters,
- `digit()`: matches any digit,
- `eof()`: matches EOF flag of a string,
- `regex(pattern)`: matches a provided regex pattern,
- `one_of(str)`: matches any character from the provided string,
- `none_of(str)`: match characters which are not in the provided string.

---

We can separate them with operators, according to the docs:

- `|`: This combinator implements choice. The parser p | q first applies p.
      If it succeeds, the value of p is returned.
      If p fails **without consuming any input**, parser q is tried.
      NOTICE: without backtrack,
- `+`: Joint two or more parsers into one. Return the aggregate of two results
      from this two parser.
- `^`: Choice with backtrack. This combinator is used whenever arbitrary
      look ahead is needed. The parser p || q first applies p, if it success,
      the value of p is returned. If p fails, it pretends that it hasn't consumed
      any input, and then parser q is tried.
- `<<`: Ends with a specified parser, and at the end parser consumed the
      end flag,
- `<`: Ends with a specified parser, and at the end parser hasn't consumed
      any input,
- `>>`: Sequentially compose two actions, discarding any value produced
      by the first,
- `mark(p)`: Marks the line and column information of the result of the parser `p`.

---

Then there are multiple "combinators":

- `times(p, mint, maxt=None)`: Repeats parser `p` from `mint` to `maxt` times,
- `count(p,n)`: Repeats parser `p` `n`-times. If `n` is smaller or equal to zero, the parser equals to return empty list,
- `(p, default_value=None)`: Make a parser optional. If success, return the result, otherwise return `default_value` silently, without raising any exception. If `default_value` is not provided `None` is returned instead,
- `many(p)`: Repeat parser `p` from never to infinitely many times,
- `many1(p)`: Repeat parser `p` at least once,
- `separated(p, sep, mint, maxt=None, end=None)`: ,
- `sepBy(p, sep)`: parses zero or more occurrences of parser `p`, separated by delimiter `sep`,
- `sepBy1(p, sep)`: parses at least one occurrence of parser `p`, separated by delimiter `sep`,
- `endBy(p, sep)`: parses zero or more occurrences of `p`, separated and ended by `sep`,
- `endBy1(p, sep)`: parses at least one occurrence of `p`, separated and ended by `sep`,
- `sepEndBy(p, sep)`: parses zero or more occurrences of `p`, separated and optionally ended by `sep`,
- `sepEndBy1(p, sep)`: parses at least one occurrence of `p`, separated and optionally ended by `sep`.

---

Using all of that, we have a parser which matches many occurrences of many `possible_chars`, followed by a `<`, then we mark the many occurrences of `possible_chars` up until `>`.

Comment: Thank you, this is very thorough and helpful.  Can I ask you two follow-ups? 1. The import * seems non-idiomatic. Do you think this is the only sensible way to use this library all the same? 2. This looks like a great extraction---how would you use this library to make a dictionary-like object like the parse I tried to sketch out?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, is there a documentation with similar explanation? Could you provide an example for each? Also, why do talk about `A || B` in the `^` bullet point?

Answer (score 4):

As others noted, the parse function needs to accept two arguments.
The syntax for multiple input args is:`lambda x, y: ...`

Unfortunately `lambda` is not suitable for building a parsec Parser this way since you need to return a `parsec.Value` type not a boolean, so it will quickly lose its terseness.

The design of parsec requires a `Parser` to act independently on an input stream without knowledge of any other Parser. To do this effectively a Parser must manage an index position of the input string. They receive the starting index position and return the next position after consuming some tokens. This is why a `parsec.Value` is returned (boolean, output index) and an input index is required along with an input string.

Here's a basic example consuming a `<` token, to illustrate:

```
import parsec

def parse_start_tag(stream, index):
    if stream[0] == '<':
        return parsec.Value.success(index + 1, stream[1:])
    else:
        return parsec.Value.failure(index, '<')

tag_open = parsec.Parser(parse_start_tag)
print(tag_open.parse("<tag>")) # prints: "tag>"
print(tag_open.parse("tag>"))  # fails:   "expected <"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the parser requires a function that has two alternative results (and two parameters), you may consider breaking the function argument rather than trying to do it with an inline function definition (`lambda`)

> A Parser is an object that wraps a function to do the parsing work.
>   Arguments of the function should be a string to be parsed and the
>   index on which to begin parsing. The function should return either
>   Value.success(next_index, value) if parsing successfully, or
>   Value.failure(index, expected) on the failure

But if you want to use a lambda expression anyway you can specify both required parameters maybe with a lambda like:  (Not real sure how the `Value.success` or `Value.failure` are expected to work without reading through the docs.)

```
lamdba x,y: Value.Success(y+1, x) if x[y] == "<" else Value.failure(y, x)
```